# Rails/Rack: retrieving request params from within canonical_host middleware

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rack

I'm using the Rack Canonical Host middleware (https://github.com/tylerhunt/rack-canonical-host) with Rails to force the www for all root requests (example.com becomes www.example.com).  However, if a visitor is attempting to access a valid subdomain of our app, we obviously don't want to force www.  Here's the example usage of the middleware:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use Rack::CanonicalHost do
  # the following return value will be used to set the canonical host
  'www.example.com'
end
```

As you can see it's somewhat static, which is a problem.  However, if I had access to the request parameters (eg subdomain, domain, etc) I could check against them, and redirect accordingly (and only if need be).

Anyone have any pointers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Specify a parameter for this block

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use Rack::CanonicalHost do |params|
  puts "PATH_INFO #{params['PATH_INFO']}"
end
```